# r- max values of a row

Tags: r, type-conversion, row

I need to find the max value from a row, excluding the first column (which is a character).

I have a table MDist

```
> MDist
          c.1. V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7    V8
1 repeticiones  0  0  1  1  1  2  <NA>
2         dias  0  0 12 15 20 28 sumas
3            0 NA NA NA NA NA NA     0
4            0 NA NA NA NA NA NA     0
5           12 NA NA  0  3  8 30    41
6           15 NA NA  3  0  5 26    34
7           20 NA NA  8  5  0 16    29
8           28 NA NA 15 13  8  0    36
```

I keep only the last column and transpose it:

```
> b<-data.frame(t(MDist[2:nrow(MDist), ncol(MDist)]))
> b
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
1 sumas  0  0 41 34 29 36


sapply(b,class)

      X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6       X7 
"factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor" "factor"
```

When I try to convert it to numeric, I get a vector full of 1.

```
> c<-as.numeric(b[1,2:ncol(b)])
> c

[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Also with as.numeric(as.character)) I get the same issue:

```
> as.numeric(as.character(b[1,2:ncol(b)]))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I need to get a line with every value of the original table (`b`) divided by the maximum value of that line. That would be :

```
0 0 1 34/41 29/41 36/41
```

Comment: Use `as.numeric(as.character(b[1,2:ncol(b)]))` instead.

Comment: @nrussell I get the same result:> as.numeric(as.character(b[1,2:ncol(b)]))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: Let's go back to how you read in your data.  Something's not right if those columns are `factor` and you expect them to be `numeric`.  How did you read the data into R?  Don't expect the result to be correct if you convert factors to numerics and then take the max.

Comment: @RichardScriven because b is a transposed matrix where the numbers were numeric. Please see the edition of the post. I added the previous steps

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting the numerators from in your desired result

Comment: @Gaby P Your original table is `MDist` or `b`?  For me `MDist[2:nrow(MDist), ncol(MDist)]#[1] sumas 0     0     41    34    29    36` This is just a single column

Comment: @akrun. My original table is MDist, and yes, I only take one column from the table in this case.

Comment: You get all `factors` because you transpose the dataset, which gives a `matrix` and if you have a single `character` column, all the other columns get changed to `character`.  When you convert it to `data.frame` without `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, those columns will get convert to `factor`.

Comment: @akrun, thanks, but if I do > b<-data.frame(t(MDist[2:nrow(MDist), ncol(MDist)]), stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
I get all characters and not numeric data.

Comment: @Gaby P Yes, that is what I mentioned about the conversion to matrix.  Matrix can hold only a single class.  It works best when all your columns are numeric.  Otherwise, with only one character column, all the others would convert to character.  So, converting to data.frame,will not automatically reconvert the character to numeric.  I don't even understand the reason for using `t`.  Why can't this calculation be done while keeping it in the original structure? Please check my updated post where a similar calculation was done with the original dataset.

Comment: @akrun thanks, So, if the values in the matrix were all characters because I had al least one character, why I was able to do elementwise operations (With MDist[i.j]?

Comment: @Gaby P Because `MDist` is a `data.frame` (I haven't seen the `str(MDist)`) which can hold several `classes`.  If you want to transpose the `data.frame`. Identify the columns that are numeric and do the transpose  `t(MDist[sapply(MDist, is.numeric)])`  Having said that I don't think doing `transpose` is that efficient. You could do the rowwise operations with `rowSums`, rowMeans` etc and of course `pmax`, `pmin` which works with `data.frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also:

```
within(MDist, rowMax <- do.call(`pmax`, 
    c(MDist[sapply(MDist, is.numeric)], na.rm=TRUE)))
#              c.1. V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7    V8 rowMax
#1 repeticiones  0  0  1  1  1  2  <NA>      2
#2         dias  0  0 12 15 20 28 sumas     28
#3            0 NA NA NA NA NA NA     0     NA
#4            0 NA NA NA NA NA NA     0     NA
#5           12 NA NA  0  3  8 30    41     30
#6           15 NA NA  3  0  5 26    34     26
#7           20 NA NA  8  5  0 16    29     16
#8           28 NA NA 15 13  8  0    36     15
```

If you are looking for dividing the last column with the `max` of that column

```
MDist[,ncol(MDist)] <- as.numeric(as.character(MDist[, ncol(MDist)]))
MDist[,ncol(MDist)]/max(MDist[,ncol(MDist)], na.rm=TRUE)
# [1]        NA        NA 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.8292683 0.7073171
#[8] 0.8780488
```

#### data

```
MDist <- structure(list(c.1. = structure(c(7L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L), .Label = c("0", "12", "15", "20", "28", "dias", "repeticiones"
), class = "factor"), V2 = c(0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
V3 = c(0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V4 = c(1L, 12L, NA, 
NA, 0L, 3L, 8L, 15L), V5 = c(1L, 15L, NA, NA, 3L, 0L, 5L, 
13L), V6 = c(1L, 20L, NA, NA, 8L, 5L, 0L, 8L), V7 = c(2L, 
28L, NA, NA, 30L, 26L, 16L, 0L), V8 = structure(c(6L, 7L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("0", "29", "34", "36", 
"41", "<NA>", "sumas"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("c.1.", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used lapply. It worked but I would like to understand better why I wasn't able to do it the other way.

```
> as.numeric(lapply(b[1,2:ncol(b)], as.character))
[1]  0  0 41 34 29 36
```